# What is the use of assigning a value to the function in this case?

Tags: c++, pointers

I cannot understand what `compare(a,b)=-1;` does in this code. All I am seeing is that this value(-1) is getting assigned to the lower no. variable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int &compare(int &c ,int &d) {
   if (c>d)
      return c;
   else
      return d;
} 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
   int a,b,j;
   std::cin >> a>>b;
   compare(a,b)=-1;
   std::cout <<a<<b<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The return value of the function is a *reference* to either `a` or `b` and -1 is assigned to it.

Comment: compare(a,b)=-1 is to assign the greater variable as -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returns a reference to the greater argument, so that it can be modified.

`compare(a,b)` returns a reference to `a` (resp. `b`) if `a` (resp. `b`) is greater than `b` (resp. `a`), and `compare(a,b) = -1` assigns `-1` to the function result (the greatest element).

For example:

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
compare(a,b) = -1;
```

After this we have: `a=1, b=-1`.